# JointJS/Rappid performance problems in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jointjs, rappid

Does anyone have suggestions for improving the performance of Rappid?

It has to run in IE (which is performing 10x slower than Chrome).
Loading a graph with 1000 squares and 1000 connectors is taking **215s**.

I don't have anything fancy in my code, I'm just loading the graph from a JSON file:

```
graph.fromJSON(JSON.parse(input));
```

My paper is set to **async = true**, which offers a large boost. And loading from JSON seems to be significantly faster than creating all the nodes programmatically.

I've tried the suggestions here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jointjs/dbdOrINRG8o but I couldn't get FastPaper working in IE at all.

Comment: Rappid uses SVG elements which will never be performant at scale. To render a lot of nodes try an HTML canvas-based library instead like http://gojs.net

Answer (score 1):

rendering only visible elements can help you **a lot**, but it's not for free...

`graph.fromJSON(JSON.parse(input));` imports all cells into the graph, `paper` detects this change and starts with rendering. In this moment you have all cells with positions and sizes in graph, as well as viewport(visible area). Now you need to to filter elements which are currently in the viewport and renderd just them.

- get the viewport: `var viewport = paperScroller.getVisibleArea()`
- get elements in viewport: `graph.findModelsInArea(viewport)`

then, you need to extend `dia.Paper` and override the `renderView` method. It should look like this:

```
joint.dia.PartialRenderPaper = joint.dia.Paper.extend({

    isVisible: function(cell) { 
        // detection logic
    },
    renderView: function(cell) {


        if (this.isVisible(cell) || cell.isLink()) {

             return joint.dia.Paper.prototype.renderView.apply(this, arguments);
        }

        return null;
    },

});
```